# How to bring the context "back" after running read_homefile()?

Tags: python, scripting

When I run

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()
```

and then I replace the above with this (in the same text data block)

```
import bpy
rrr = bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
print("select_all result:", rrr)
print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context:", bpy.context)
print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object:", bpy.context.object)
print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object.name:", bpy.context.object.name)
```

and run it, I get this

```
select_all result: {'FINISHED'}
>>>>>>>>>> bpy.context: <bpy_struct, Context at 0x000000EEA420B5C8>
>>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object: <bpy_struct, Object("Cube")>
>>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object.name: Cube
```

However, when I run this (same code but merged)

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()
rrr = bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
print("select_all result:", rrr)
print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context:", bpy.context)
print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object:", bpy.context.object)
print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object.name:", bpy.context.object.name)
```

I get this

```
select_all result: {'PASS_THROUGH'}
>>>>>>>>>> bpy.context: <bpy_struct, Context at 0x000000EEA420B5C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Why does that happen?

Is there a way to make the code after `bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()` work "normally"?

**Edit:**
It seems that `bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()` effectively "clears" the context - the `bpy.context.area` is `None`.

So the new question is **how to bring the context back to the correct area?**

**Edit 2:**
I have found a workaround that searches for 3D View area and makes it current context - and here is the dubious part - by calling `bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area()`:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()
havesetthecontext = False
for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        print("area=", area)
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)   # toggle to maximize
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area()           # toggle back (must not use overridden context, else it will crash!)
            havesetthecontext = True
            break

if havesetthecontext:
    rrr = bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    print("select_all result:", rrr)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context:", bpy.context)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object:", bpy.context.object)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object.name:", bpy.context.object.name)
else:
    print("Could not set the context to 3D View!")
```

Now, **isn't there a way to set a context directly**, something like `bpy.context.set(override)`?

**Edit 3:**
The above workaround is unstable (occasionally crashes Blender) unless Load UI is disabled.
So, add this line before calling `bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()`:

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.filepaths.use_load_ui = False
```

That, of course, kind of kills the purpose of reloading startup file, unfortunately.

Oh, and the same issues appear when calling `read_factory_settings()`.

When I run the screen_full_area() stuff from `load_handler` then it does not crash, however, in the "main" code the `bpy.context.area` is still `None` - and when I do screen_full_area() stuff there too, it crashes again.

I suspect that crashing is due to some code in screen_full_area(), not the context changing, so we are back to the question **is there a way to set the context directly?**

Comment: I believe it's a matter of time you have to wait until the loading is done, the code is executed  while the loading is done

Comment: you may try to append you code to the handler  `load_post` to be executed after loading a new file

Comment: @Chebhou, thanks, but it looks like read_homefile() returns only after the file is loaded. I can access the Cube from the file immediately after the read_homefile() line. I will try the load_post handler though ...

Comment: @Chebhou, nope, load_post handler also says bpy.context.area = None.

Comment: I have found a workaround-like solution using context override with screen_full_area operator called twice ...

Comment: I can't believe this question is not solved yet. Suffering from the same problem in 2021. :P And from the Blender 2.80, you should use bpy.context. **preferences**.filepaths.use_load_ui = False

Comment: i suspect `read_homefile` and `read_factory_settings`  will have the same resolution, I put a bounty on this topic over here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220523/is-there-a-recommend-way-to-repair-or-recreate-a-valid-context-after-using-bpy

Answer (score 2):

Try this script it works for me on Blender 3.4. You have to first add the [`load_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) handler and then call `bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()` so that your code only triggers after loading is complete and the context has been properly set.

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.clear()

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    print("Load Handler:", bpy.data.filepath)
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(load_handler)

    result = bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

    print("select_all result:", result)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context:", bpy.context)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object:", bpy.context.object)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.object.name:", bpy.context.object.name)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.screen:", bpy.context.screen)
    for index, area in enumerate(bpy.context.screen.areas):
        print(f">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.screen.areas[{index}]:", area)
    print(">>>>>>>>>> bpy.context.area:", bpy.context.area)

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()
```

The `bpy.context.area` may be `None` due to a bug, I'm not sure, but that is fine because you can still access all the areas in `bpy.context.screen.areas` list.